# Disable child component to take height of parent scroll view

Tags: react-native, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view and inside of it I've some views:

```
                        <ScrollView
                            horizontal={true}
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                            {myData.map((dataObj, index) =>
                                <MyTestCell />
                            )}
                        </ScrollView>
```

The `MyTestCell` is a custom component and everything in it inside a `<View></View>`

Based on the content some `MyTestCell` are larger in height than others. Is there a way to **NOT** let `MyTestCell` `View` take the height of the longest component?

For example here is a screenshot of the bottom part of a cell which is just there because another cell in the scroll view is of that height:

[image]

So, is there a fix to this? Basically, I'm asking if there is a way to **absolute** the height of a `view` inside `scroll view` rather than inheriting the height of its parent it should just keep the height which it requires.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but you can do it but setting the `flexGrow` to 0 on the child component.